# Create SSH key without passphrase on MacOS Mojave

Tags: openssh, vagrant, ansible, macos-mojave

For years I have been using a line like this to automatically create an SSH key pair without a passphrase:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -q -b 1024 -N "" -C "vagrant@labman01" -f keys/labkey
```

I typically call ssh-keygen from an Ansible play and then proceed to provision the key to a number of vagrant guest machines when creating a lab environment.

However, since upgrading to MacOS Mojave (10.14.2) the generated key is later reported as invalid by Ansible on the Linux guests, and attempting to use the key manually on the Linux guest causes a prompt for a passphrase, as if the private key is password protected.

Doing the same on any Linux host machine, however, creates a valid key.

Is there some new trick to generate a valid, password free key pair on MacOS Mojave?

**UPDATE**

When examining the generated key file, I noticed that MacOS Mojave uses `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` instead of `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` as the PEM header. Same thing for the footer.

There appears to be a change in the key format on OpenSSH 7.8 and later. Simply changing the header does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a change in the default key file format in `OpenSSH_7.8p1` and later. `MacOS Mojave 10.14.2` ships with `OpenSSH_7.9p1`.

Adding `-m PEM` changes the behaviour of `ssh-keygen` to use the legacy PEM private key format, which was the default on previous Mac OS releases.

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -q -m PEM -b 1024 -N "" -C "vagrant@labman01" -f keys/labkey
```

Unfortunately, the -m option is not supported in earlier versions of OpenSSH, so version specific code must be maintained to sustain older OS releases.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to generate key with nonempty password and after this set the password to empty:

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -q -N "password" -f <your_key_file>
ssh-keygen -p -P "password" -N "" -f <your_key_file>
```

In case of wrong header you can try to change the text:

```
sed -i -e 's/OPENSSH/RSA/' <your_key_file>
```

Comment: A viable suggestion, though it now looks like it has to do with the formatting of the key file. See update in question.

Comment: @Roy, let add some suggestion to my answer

Comment: Aye, that's a fair workaround :-)

Comment: Oh, I think you forgot -e in the sed (too small a change for me to edit your post)

Comment: No go. Guess there is more to the format change than just the PEM header :-(